# Posting a form with a select tag with ngUplaod

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the directive ngUpload to post form with a fileupload. https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload

If you have a input tag like the one below, the "name" attribut with the input value is posted to the server.

```
<input type="text" name="pr_title" ng-model="product.pr_title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Ex: Eagle">
```

But it does not work when I have select tag:

```
<select class="form-control"   ng-model="subcategory" name="subcategory" ng-options="s.sc_title for s in subcategories"></select>
```

There is no example in the docs how to do it with select.

Any ideas?